# How to insert TimeUUID and TimeStamp with Spark Cassandra connector?

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra

I am using Spark Cassandra connector in Java to insert data. My data has a `timeuuid` and `timestamp` field. I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE abc.log (
time_uuid timeuuid,
session_id text,
event text,
time timestamp,
sequence int,
PRIMARY KEY (customer)
);
```

I am using this code to insert:

```
JavaRDD<EventLog> rdd = sc.parallelize(eventLogs);
    javaFunctions(rdd)
    .writerBuilder("dove", "event_log", mapToRow(EventLog.class))
    .saveToCassandra();
```

how do I insert the `timeuuid` and `timestamp` fields? Using normal insert I would just use the `now()` function, how do I do that here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [com.datastax.driver.core.utils.UUIDs](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/1b6b1c6eb45b829a020b91b2df8b72926fa05033/driver-core/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/core/utils/UUIDs.java) for this.
The [UUIDsTest](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/89925d290bc4bf251f6a5b2a516bdca44a2b3951/driver-core/src/test/java/com/datastax/driver/core/utils/UUIDsTest.java) utilizes the class like this to create a TimeUUID:

```
 UUID uuid = UUIDs.timeBased();
```

Note that `UUID` is `java.util.UUID`. Note sure if you need it for your use case, but after that you can retrieve timestamp of the UUID by calling `UUIDs.unixTimestamp(uuid);`.

As for your timestamp, you pass an instance of `java.util.Date`, as proposed on the [docs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/1.0/java-driver/reference/javaClass2Cql3Datatypes_r.html).